# On second loop through countdown function, number drops two seconds not one

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, countdown

It's as if the clearInterval isn't working at the end of the first loop through the work() function.

The full code is below (typescript/javascript) and the countdown phase, work phase and rest phase all seem to work fine. However, the work phase should then restart, which it does, but it counts down two seconds at a time.

I've tried moving the clearInterval positions. I've tried using this.clearInterval, but no good.

```
repeat() {
    this.startBtn.classList.remove('green');
    this.startBtn.classList.add('grey');
    this.startBtn.innerHTML = "Prepare/Rest on orange, Workout on green";
    this.intervalOne = setInterval(() => this.begin(this.countdown, this.tabata, this.displayDiv), 1000);
}

begin(myCountdown, myTabata, myDisplay) {
    this.set = this.set;
    this.displayDiv = myDisplay;
    if (this.set == 1) {
        this.countdown = myCountdown - 1;
        this.countdown > 0
        if (this.countdown < 10) {
            this.countdown = "0" + this.countdown;
        }
        this.displayDiv.innerHTML = this.countdown;
        if (this.countdown == 0) {
            clearInterval(this.intervalOne);
            this.intervalTwo = setInterval(() => this.work(this.restTime, this.set), 1000)
            this.displayDiv.classList.remove('orange');
        }
    }
}

work(myRest, set) {
    // var displayDiv = myDisplay;
    this.set = set;
    this.secondCount--;
    if (this.secondCount < 10) {
        this.secondCount = "0" + this.secondCount;
    }
    this.displayDiv.innerHTML = this.secondCount;
    if (this.secondCount == 0) {
        clearInterval(this.intervalTwo);
        this.displayDiv.classList.remove('green');
        this.displayDiv.classList.add('orange');
        this.secondCount = +this.tabata.split(':')[1];
        this.intervalTwo = setInterval(() => this.rest(this.displayDiv, this.restTime, this.set), 1000)
    }
}

rest(myDisplay, myRest, set) {
    var displayDiv = myDisplay;
    this.restTime = myRest;
    console.log("this rest time = ", this.restTime);
    this.set = set;
    this.restTime--;
    if (this.restTime < 10) {
        this.restTime = "0" + this.restTime;
    }
    displayDiv.innerHTML = this.restTime;
    if (this.restTime == 0) {
        clearInterval(this.intervalTwo);
        this.displayDiv.classList.remove('orange');
        this.displayDiv.classList.add('green');
        // this.restTime = this.restTime;
        this.secondCount = +this.tabata.split(':')[1];
        switch (this.id) {
            case this.id = "0":
                this.restTime = Math.ceil(this.secondCount * 0.5);
                break;
            case this.id = "1":
                this.restTime = Math.ceil(this.secondCount * 0.33);
                break;
            case this.id = "2":
                this.restTime = Math.ceil(this.secondCount * 0.25);
                break;
            case this.id = "3":
                this.restTime = Math.ceil(this.secondCount * 0.20);
                break;
        }
        this.set++;
        console.log("this set = ", this.set);
        this.intervalOne = setInterval(() => this.work(this.secondCount, this.set), 1000)
    }
}

previousPage() {
    const url = window.location.href;
    let id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    clearInterval(this.intervalOne);
    clearInterval(this.intervalTwo);
    this.router.navigate(['/set-timer/', id]);

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
            this.countdown = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.tabataData[0].substring(17, 19);
            this.tabata = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.tabataData[1].substring(14, 19);
            this.id = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.tabataData[2];
            this.set = 1;
            this.currentSet = "Set " + this.set + " of 8";
            this.startBtn = document.querySelector('#startBtn');
            this.displayDiv = document.querySelector('#counter');
            this.currentSetDiv = document.querySelector('#currentSet');
            let secondCount: any = +this.tabata.split(':')[1];
            this.secondCount = +this.tabata.split(':')[1];

            switch (this.id) {
                case this.id = "0":
                    this.restTime = Math.ceil(secondCount * 0.5);
                    break;
                case this.id = "1":
                    this.restTime = Math.ceil(secondCount * 0.33);
                    break;
                case this.id = "2":
                    this.restTime = Math.ceil(secondCount * 0.25);
                    break;
                case this.id = "3":
                    this.restTime = Math.ceil(secondCount * 0.20);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Any ideas how to correct this code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are having problems due to setting twice intervals.

I'd suggest instead of setting interval manually have a method to set interval where you clear it first:

```
setInterval() {
    if(this.intervalOne)
    {
        clearInterval(this.intervalOne);
        delete this.intervalOne;
    }
    this.intervalOne = setInterval(() => this.work(this.secondCount, this.set), 1000)
}
```

In this case you can be sure you will never end up with a method accidentally running multiple times

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldn't manage to fit your code into mine. However, finally I realised I was reusing the same interval variable in the work function, clearing it then calling it again. This may have been what you were trying to explain to me. 
My solution was to use a total of three setInterval variables, one different for each of the three phases of the Tabata countdown.